# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions

Tags: javascript, iphone, asp.net, ipad, postback

I'm having the strangest issue with iPhones / Droids / iPads on an ASP.NET Webforms Login page.

Everything is working, the username/password Javascript validation triggers everything... When the user pushes Submit, the page simply times out for a very long time, and this error appears.  I'm not sure if this is some strange JS / Back-end / etc type of issue!

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions

On the button itself, the generated code from ASP.NET is:

```
href='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new 
    WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$MainContent$btnSubmit", "", true, 
    "LoginUserValidationGroup", "", false, true))'
```

As for the Back-end the event doesn't do anything special besides Login validation!

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    ' Check U/Password etc...
End Sub
```

Has anyone run into this issue before??

Comment: Do you have very big ViewState ?

Comment: @Aristos Maybe at some points in the application, but this is before they have even entered it! They are merely trying to login, never seen something like this before, everyone is stumped

Comment: Maybe this is like yours ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800626/asp-net-post-timeout/5801613

Answer (score 1):

I am having this problem as well.  My first inclination is to think it is a timing issue of the script loaded by WebResource.axd that contains the WebForm_PostBackOptions function is not fully loaded when they first hit the logon button.  I suspect this is happening with a browser plugin or other tool of convenience such as LastPass that autofills and submits the login form very quickly, as soon as the form is visible but perhaps before all resources are loaded.

I am attempting to address this by putting the login form inside a hidden div and then showing the div in a jquery $(document).ready(function ().  We'll see how that works out.

Comment: Interesting, yeah this is the strangest issue, and we still haven't been able to come up with a solution for it! Let me know if that ends up fixing it! I'm also worried that once they get even past the login page, if every page on the site will be having this same issue.. @PatJames